# How to design window manager in such a way that we can touch the home screen or interact with the UI behind that window manager

Tags: android

How to design a window manager in such a way that behind that window i.e. home screen,apps can be touchable or interaction with UI of device .Mostly we can only interact with the views on the window manager but I want to interact with the home screen behind that window manager .can anyone help me

Comment: Are you building your own custom ROM with a modified version of Android? If no, then please explain what a "window manager" is. If you are creating a custom ROM, while I suspect that what you want is possible, it is likely to be *much* too broad for a Stack Overflow question.

Comment: @CommonsWare window manager uses system alert window permission and is used to display some views on it and it can  be used outside the activity .

Comment: Then please explain what "interact with the home screen behind that window manager" means.

Comment: @CommonsWare when we launch our window on screen.The window can receive touch for it only, and it blocks UI touch that is hidden behind it.I want to make it such that we can also interact with the UI of mobile screen which is hidden behind the window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible, short of building your own custom ROM with your own custom Android build.

Generally speaking, touch events are delivered to the window highest on the Z axis at the X/Y coordinate of the touch event. If your window is highest on the Z axis, you get the touch events.

What is possible in theory, but not available to app developers, is to have some sort of API that "punches holes" in your window. In those holes, the touch events would not go to your window, but rather to whatever is next-highest on the Z axis at that X/Y coordinate. This would require some OS modification.

If, however, you are seeking some way that you can see the touch events, then dispatch them yourself to the underlying windows, that is blocked for obvious privacy and security reasons.

Comment: OK thanks for your help.one more question how can I build an app that lower down the screen brightness up to 1% that means the screen will look blackish .This type of operation is done by some night mode app ,I tried lowering screen brightness programmatically but it lowered up to some extent only.can you help me please

Comment: @Rachan: I have no idea, sorry.